# How can I compile Boost with VS2013 (64-bit)

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2013

I'm using the following command to compile Boost 1.55 beta 1:

> b2 --toolset=msvc-12.0 architecture=x86 address-model=64 stage

The result is a bunch of these errors:

> error C3861: 'assert_not_arg': identifier not found

There is a list of supposed patches to make boost work with VS2013 [here](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2013/07/204953.php), but I have no idea how to use them. Apparently [a similar problem is documented here](http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2013/10/80254.php), but I was wondering if anyone had had success building Boost 64-bit for VS2013 (I don't mind using an older version of boost, but they don't seem to support the MSVC 12.0 compiler).

Comment: I've built 64-bit boost with MSVS2013 from svn, but a little bit earlier, without any problems. So you just need to wait until your error is fixed or fix it yourself and build it. Or try to check out svn maybe the bug is fixed already.

Comment: @ixSci thanks the latest svn seems to work :)

Comment: @ixSci will these changes make it into the 1.55 release, or will that have to wait till later versions?

Comment: I'm not boost dev, but I'm pretty sure they won't publish anything that can't be compiled by one of the major compilers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Built with the latest SVN repository build and it seems to work using the above commands.